# Apply function to every element in a list in a df column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

How do I apply a function to every element in a list in every row of a dataframe?

df:

```
label   top_topics               
adverts ['werbung', 'geschenke']
```

my function looks something like this:

```
from langdetect import detect
from googletrans import Translator

def detect_and_translate(text):
    
    target_lang = 'en'
    try:
        result_lang = detect(text)
        
    except:
        result_lang = target_lang
    
    if result_lang == target_lang:
        
        return text, result_lang
    
    else:
        translator = Translator()
        translated_text = translator.translate(text, dest=target_lang)
        return translated_text.text, result_lang
```

expecting an output like :

```
 label        top_topics                 translation             language

 adverts    ['werbung', 'geschenke']       ['advertising', 'gifts']   de
```

I tried something like this but didn't translate the column `top_topics` as it couldn't loop through every element in the list.

```
df['translate_detect'] = df['top_topics'].apply(detect_and_translate)
df['top_topics_en'], df['language'] = df.translate_detect.str
```

Any help?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I did provide. Please check properly. @ddejohn

Comment: Please read the linked article. Your example data are not copy-paste-able. Please also see how to provide a [sample dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [you should never use a bare `except`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except).

Second, because your function translates a single word and returns the translated word and the detected language as a tuple, it would be difficult and tedious to achieve your desired output of a list of translated words and a single detected language. Instead, modify your function to do so:

```py
import googletrans


def detect_and_translate(lst):
    translator = Translator()
    target_lang = 'en'
    try:
        result_lang = translator.detect(lst[0])
    except Exception:  # should be the specific exception that can occur
        return lst, result_lang

    translations = []
    for text in lst:
        translated_text = translator.translate(text, dest=target_lang)
        translations.append(translated_text.text)

    return translations, result_lang
```

Usage:

```py
In [4]: googletrans.__version__
Out[4]: '4.0.0-rc.1'

In [5]: df[["topics_en", "language"]] = df.top_topics.apply(detect_and_translate).apply(pd.Series)

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
     label            top_topics             topics_en                            language
0  adverts  [werbung, geschenke]  [advertising, gifts]  Detected(lang=de, confidence=None)
```

Note that `googletrans.Translator` [has a language detection method](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#googletrans.Translator.detect). It doesn't work in `3.0.0` but if you `pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1` it will.

Note also that in order for this to work, you must assume that all words in a given list are the same language. If that's not an assumption you can make, you'll need to figure something else out.

Comment: Hi Thanks ! Your solution partly works, as I need the output in 2 different columns, with this I get tuples in a list.

Comment: The problem here is that your function is not designed to provide the output you want. Your function takes one word at a time and returns the tuple `(translated_word, original_language)`, **for each word**. You will need to spend some time thinking about how to go about doing that, since it's not as simple as translating all the words and then returning `list_of_translated_words, original_language` since it may be possible that you get a list of words from multiple languages (e.g., `["pompelmo", "pamplemousse"]` -- it would be incorrect to return `["grapefruit", "grapefruit"], IT`).

Comment: If you're okay to make the assumption that all words in a given list will be the same language, see my edit.

Comment: perfect works well now! :) Thanks, I wanted to actually use the same function for both lists and strings, but I have used your implementation and handled it with some if-else to check the type of input and have my final function! :)